# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_sqlagent_is_starting', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
>   'xp_sqlagent_is_starting', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema
>   'sys'.

I get this error in my application. But when I run my program in visual studio it works fine. I am lost been stuck on this for days.

It happens on every user. can anyone help.

My program is written with visual basic, sql server 2012.

Comment: Sounds like you need to grant `Execute` permission to your user's... For example: `GRANT execute on master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting TO {username}`...

Comment: If there is another team which handles the DB, request them to provide the execute permissions for this database table on the required schema. First execute your query and validate your results in any of the DB tools before using the query directly on the application.

Comment: I am the only developer, (full stack). How do I grant right for all users.